# Xcode how to retrieve a file from the documents folder and open it in another app

Tags: xcode, file

I want to get a file that is in the documents folder of the app, and present something that asks you what app you want to open the file in. Like when you are in mail, you open a PDF (or whatever file it is) at there is a button at the top right which is a rectangle with an arrow coming out of it. Like https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=ipad+pdf+in+mail&oe=UTF-8&hl=es&client=safari&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=Kcw6UYOWBamOygHXwIGIDw&biw=1024&bih=672&sei=K8w6UcCKKMPmygH8zIHYCQ#biv=i%7C5%3Bd%7CEH2RwCFWjmcvjM%3A but the iOS 6 version of it (it has the app icons above the name and in a 3x3 grid). When the user clicks the icon it should go to that app and the app will do whatever with the file

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is the functionality provided by [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Which looks like this on the iPad:

[image: Activity View Controller]

You can set it up using [`[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: ]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIDocumentInteractionController/interactionControllerWithURL:) (passing a URL to the file) and then present it via [`[UIDocumentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIDocumentInteractionController/presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated:).

Comment: Thanks for replying quickly. Could you give me an example as to how I would write this exactly?

Comment: better than that, [Apple has some great documentation with lines of sample code too](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010410-SW1).

Comment: My app crashes at my terrible attempt attempt at it.

Comment: This is my code:
        `UIDocumentInteractionController *controller = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
        controller.delegate = self;
        BOOL wasAbleToOpenMenu = [controller presentOpenInMenuFromRect:_button.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
        if (wasAbleToOpenMenu == NO) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Converter" message:@"There were no apps able to open the file type entered" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
        }
`

Comment: i worked out its something to do with writing a file with this line of code

Comment: `BOOL hasMadeFile = [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];` It returns NO.

Comment: i should say that i had these lines of code before: ` NSData *data = [newString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSURL *pathURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        NSString *path = [pathURL absoluteString];
        
        if ([_fileTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Flashcard.txt"];
        } else {
            path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _fileTextField.text]];
        }
        
`

Comment: ignore my previous comments. the write to file now returns yes so i have a file now, but i get the error: Assertion failure in -[UIDocumentInteractionController setURL:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UIDocumentInteractionController.m:960
2013-03-09 23:12:41.667 TableToFlashcardFileConverter[15595:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UIDocumentInteractionController: invalid scheme (null).  Only the file scheme is supported.'

Comment: i tried it again and i got: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UIDocumentInteractionController: invalid scheme (null).  Only the file scheme is supported.'

Comment: Hi Dylan, it looks like you're trying to use paths in your code up there. UIDocumentInteractionController only works with file URLs (which are not paths, even though they have paths as part of the URL).  Have you got it figured out yet?

Comment: I've always used the code [NSURL URLWithString:path] where I enter my path.

Comment: Well, from the error you're showing up there, it sure looks to me like the item that you are passing into `[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:]` is invalid.  You might want to work back from that and see why it isn't a file URL.

Comment: i figured out that i had to use the [NSURL fileURLWithPath: ] method. but i don't have any apps on the simulator to open it with so i don't know whether it works or  not

Comment: AHA! it was because i declared the controller within the method so when the method finished running it crashed. i moved the declaration to an @property and it worked!